# How to configure tasks.json in VScode to run a .c file that depends on other .c files? (assuming everything is in the same folder)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a .c file that depends on other .c files which I would like to run. I have the appropriate headers files and #include statements as well. However, I keep getting an "undefined reference error" when trying to run my program.

tasks.json file (I have also tried using "${fileDirname}\*.cpp" as well as "${fileDirname}\*.cpp", "${workspaceFolder}\*.cpp", etc. including adding "${workspaceFolder}\*.h" as well)

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "parser.cpp",
                "tester.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

code I am trying to run

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "scanner.h"
#include "core.h"
#include "parser.h"

void compareFiles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
    // fetching character of two file
    // in two variable ch1 and ch2
    char ch1 = getc(fp1);
    char ch2 = getc(fp2);
    printf("char1 = %c, char2 = %c\n", ch1, ch2);
  
    // error keeps track of number of errors
    // pos keeps track of position of errors
    // line keeps track of error line
    int error = 0, pos = 0, line = 1;
  
    // iterate loop till end of file
    while (ch1 != EOF && ch2 != EOF)
    {
        pos++;
  
        // if both variable encounters new
        // line then line variable is incremented
        // and pos variable is set to 0
        if (ch1 == '\n' && ch2 == '\n')
        {
            line++;
            pos = 0;
        }
  
        // if fetched data is not equal then
        // error is incremented
        if (ch1 != ch2)
        {
            error++;
            printf("Line Number : %d \tError"
               " Position : %d \n", line, pos);
        }
  
        // fetching character until end of file
        ch1 = getc(fp1);
        ch2 = getc(fp2);
    }
  
    printf("Total Errors : %d\t", error);
}
  
// Driver code
int main()
{
    parser();
    // opening both file in read only mode
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "r");
  
    if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL)
    {
       printf("Error : Files not open");
       exit(0);
    }
  
    compareFiles(fp1, fp2);
  
    // closing both file
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

the .c file it depends on

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "scanner.h"
#include "core.h"

void parser() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "hello this is a test\n");
    fprintf(fp, " still a test");
}
```

the corresponding header file

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

void parser();

#endif
```

and finally the error message

```
[Running] cd "q:\CProgramming\" && gcc tester.c -o tester && "q:\CProgramming\"tester
C:\Users\PATRIC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc22NK4v.o:tester.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `parser'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.231 seconds
```

Comment: It looks like you're not compiling your parser.c file and linking the compiled parser object file into the tester.c executable. But you really need to provide a [mre]. You should also read and follow the guidance in [ask].

Comment: thats a linker error, it means that it cannot find the executable code for 'parser'

Comment: How would I change the tasks.json file to do that? Also was not aware of the minimal reproducible example, I apologize. Although in this case the main is literally just calling parser() one time because all I was trying to do is set up VScode to let me use .h files so that I don't have to write all my code in one file

Comment: So where *is* the implementation `void parser() { }`?

Comment: @WeatherVane just realized I missed that. Added it to the post

Comment: Please do not post code as pictures. Copy it as text, instead.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica got it, my apologies

Comment: Note: If you feel like learning more, go down the CMake rabbit hole. Also, emphasis on "minimal" and "example" in [mre]. What you've now shown is probably reproducible, but probably not minimal or an example.

Comment: note that the json file you show is compiling xxxx.cpp but you are actually compiling xx.c. THat suggests you are not editing the correct config file

Comment: You really should use a build system such as CMake. VS Code supports it, and it doesn't tie you to a specific IDE. Even though I love VS Code and use it exclusively, I still wouldn't make a build system out of it.

Comment: @swineone I just spent the last 45 minutes trying to use CMake but I keep getting an error that there are zero answers for online so that option is now out for me (if you're curious, Im getting "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found" and I am using mingw compiler, which is what I chose for my kit" No answers online tackle this specific problem)

Comment: You can pass `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=<path to your compiler executable>` when calling `cmake` from the command line.